# SQL Server 2012 Installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Not sure if this is the correct forum to ask.
Is there a way to combine both x86 and x64 setups of SQL Server 2012 installation. In previous versions we had both installers in single iso, where depending on option or detected architecture corresponding setup is invoked. But in 2012 we are having different iso's for 32 and 64 bit. Since we are shipping SQL server we need to combine the installers.

Any idea on how this can be achieved ?

Thanks in advance,
Dheena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) has combined installer DVD images for x32 and x64, so a first step would be talking to your Microsoft representative to see if you could get access to those (or similar) DVDs for distribution.

> SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition (x86 and x64) - DVD (English)
>   SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core Edition (x86 and x64) - DVD (English)
>   SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition (x86 and x64) - DVD (English)
>   ...